# My page not loading when it get to registration or login part

Tags: php

Please i'm seeing this error code how do i fix it ??

On my site the registration form is connected to the database via database.php but I am having trouble in submitting the details after clicking submit then i will get the below error message on my screen.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "pairs" not found in /home/tyweavao/public_html/fbank/connections/config.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /home/tyweavao/public_html/fbank/app/init.php(3): require() #1 /home/tyweavao/public_html/fbank/app/register.php(5): require('/home/tyweavao/...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/tyweavao/public_html/fbank/connections/config.php on line 11

I have tried to look through my script but i couldn't find the error and my developer isn't active to help me out.

Comment: The class is not included.

Comment: Figure out what file pairs exists in and make sure it is included/required etc..